# convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{n}a_n$ implies the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How the convergence  of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{n}a_n$ implies the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$?

I know this if $a_n>0$. But for arbitrary $a_n$, I have no idea...

Comment: @Albert How does that answer the question, though?

Comment: But $a_n \to 0$ does not imply the convergence of $\sum a_n$

Comment: Use the ratio test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a situation for [Abel's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Abel.27s_test), quite useful in this non absolutely convergent series case:

1. The series $c_n = \sqrt{n}a_n $ yields a convergent sum,
2. $b_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is monotone and bounded.

Then $\sum_\limits{n} b_n c_n = \sum_\limits{n} a_n $ is convergent too.

Comment: :I wanted to do this problem just by using the necessary condition for the convergence of series i.e., $\lim_{n\to \infty} c_n$=0.Since $\sum_{n} c_n$ is convergent,this means that $a_n$ be some decreasing sequence.Now in order to show that $a_n$ is convergent sequence in $\mathbb R$ so $a_n$ should be a cauchy sequnce.How can i show that $a_n$ is a cauchy sequence?

Comment: Would that be a different question?

Answer (score 4):

Follows from Abel's theorem : If $\sum c_n$ converges and $\{d_n\}$ is monotone and bounded then $\sum c_nd_n$ converges. Let $c_n=\sqrt{n}a_n$ and $d_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: I think the statement is the other way round: If every finite sum (i.e. $N$) we have $|\sum_{1\le n \le N} c_n|<M$ for some $M \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $(d_n)$ is monotone and has $0$ as a limit then $ \sum c_n d_n$ converges.

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski Thats Dirichlet's theorem.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, my bad!